# Python: Pandas function KeyError (algo-trading)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithmic-trading

My probem is about how can I apply a function in my code
I've tried until now to solve it but i always get errors.

```
def ichimoku_kinko_hyo(Data):
  # Tenkan-sen (Conversion Line): (9-period high + 9-period low)/2))
  nine_period_high = Data['High'].rolling(window= 9).max()
  nine_period_low = Data['Low'].rolling(window= 9).min()
  Data['tenkan_sen'] = (nine_period_high + nine_period_low) /2
  tenkan_sen= Data['tenkan_sen']
  
  # Kijun-sen (Base Line): (26-period high + 26-period low)/2))
  period26_high = Data['High'].rolling(window=26).max()
  period26_low = Data['Low'].rolling(window=26).min()
  Data['kijun_sen'] = (period26_high + period26_low) / 2
  kijun_sen= Data['kijun_sen']
  # Senkou Span A (Leading Span A): (Conversion Line + Base Line)/2))
  Data['senkou_span_a'] = ((Data['tenkan_sen'] + Data['kijun_sen']) / 2).shift(26)
  senkou_span_a= Data['senkou_span_a']

  # Senkou Span B (Leading Span B): (52-period high + 52-period low)/2))
  period52_high = Data['High'].rolling(window=52).max()
  period52_low = Data['Low'].rolling(window=52).min()
  Data['senkou_span_b'] = ((period52_high + period52_low) / 2).shift(26)
  senkou_span_b= Data['senkou_span_b']
  # The most current closing price plotted 26 time periods behind (optional)
  Data['chikou_span'] = Data['Close'].shift(-26)
  chikou_span= Data['chikou_span']

  return Data

def signal(Data):
 for i in range(len(Data)):
   if Data.iloc[i]['tenkan_sen'] > Data.iloc[i]['kijun_sen'] and Data.iloc[i - 1]['tenkan_sen'] < Data.iloc[i - 1]['kijun_sen'] and Data.iloc[i]['Close'] > Data[i]['senkou_span_a'] and Data.iloc[i]['Close'] > Data.iloc[i]['senkou_span_b'] and Data.iloc[i - 26]['chikou_span'] > Data.iloc[i - 26]['Close']:
    Data.iloc[i]['buy'] = 1 
   else:
    Data.iloc[i]['buy'] = 0

signal(data)
```

And here's the head of my 'data' or DataFrame

```
Date        Open        High        Low         Close       Adj Close   Volume              
2021-02-22  1935.557861 1936.453735 1580.626587 1781.992920 1781.992920 42409646036
2021-02-23  1781.409058 1781.409058 1378.840942 1570.203979 1570.203979 52029864713
2021-02-24  1571.476440 1710.983765 1511.018921 1626.575684 1626.575684 31329000537
2021-02-25  1625.393921 1670.224121 1465.058960 1475.703735 1475.703735 24481681873
2021-02-26  1478.653320 1559.028931 1407.979248 1446.033691 1446.033691 31435997881
```

This is the error i'm getting while running this code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py:1056: SettingWithCopyWarning:


A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1724: SettingWithCopyWarning:


A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
```

How can I apply this code to my Data? It doesn't matter if there's NAN's missing values.

Comment: I am adding values to a signal function with a conditional decision, but don't I need to add columns beforehand? The timing judgment column is added when the column is added. `Def signal(Data):Data['buy'] = 0...`

Comment: And the error did not occur in my environment in the first place. Here is what I did to correct your code. `data = ichimoku_kinko_hyo(data);df = signal(data)` Added `return Data` for the return value of the post-signal function.

Comment: I tried your solution but....it gets me an error: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 112

Comment: I have modified your code and expanded it to [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mJcDSMU_ykp1SRxupoburzdlnj1UnHMh?usp=sharing). Please check it out for reference. Once you confirm, this link will be invalid.

Comment: Thank you very much! but if i changed the time intervall (data) it gets me the same error as previously

Comment: Check my colab notebook [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QKekRU-6752J_ad2zUb-aDXh5DFpAiu7?usp=sharing)!

Comment: If you are referring to time intervals for time series indexing, I think it is best to delete Na at the end of the results if that is what you are concerned about. And I don't see any errors in my local environment with your Colab code.

Comment: But I always get errors do I have a problem in my colab account ? here is the error. KeyError: 69
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans

Comment: As for NA, I replaced it with all zeros before discovering the error. So I checked the signal's decision conditions one by one. The line specification of this condition was incorrect. Can I reply with this information if my point solves the problem? `print(Data.iloc[i]['Close'] > Data.iloc[i]['senkou_span_a'])` is collect. and `Data.fillna(0,inplace=True)`

Comment: Yeah you can answer ! I'm very grateful to know that there is good people like you, may happiness be with you forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for debugging the error.

1. Checked the output of error rows.
2. Since NA is an issue, we replaced NA with 0 for all columns.
3. Since the conditional judgment of the signal is an issue, we disassembled and checked one condition at a time.
4. We confirmed that the row specification for the third judgment was missing.

```
   def signal(Data):
        Data = ichimoku_kinko_hyo(Data)
        #print(Data.iloc[69])
        Data.fillna(0, inplace=True)
        #print(Data.info())
        Data['buy'] = 0
        for i in range(len(Data)):
            print(Data.iloc[i])
            print(Data.iloc[i]['tenkan_sen'] > Data.iloc[i]['kijun_sen'])
            print(Data.iloc[i - 1]['tenkan_sen'] < Data.iloc[i - 1]['kijun_sen'])
            print(Data.iloc[i]['Close'] > Data.iloc[i]['senkou_span_a']) # updated
            print(Data.iloc[i]['Close'] > Data.iloc[i]['senkou_span_b'])
            print(Data.iloc[i - 26]['chikou_span'] > Data.iloc[i - 26]['Close'])
            if Data.iloc[i]['tenkan_sen'] > Data.iloc[i]['kijun_sen'] and Data.iloc[i - 1]['tenkan_sen'] < Data.iloc[i - 1]['kijun_sen'] and Data.iloc[i]['Close'] > Data.loc[i]['senkou_span_a'] and Data.iloc[i]['Close'] > Data.iloc[i]['senkou_span_b'] and Data.iloc[i - 26]['chikou_span'] > Data.iloc[i - 26]['Close']:
                 Data.iloc[i]['buy'] = 1 
            else:
                Data.iloc[i]['buy'] = 0
        return Data
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at this [video](https://youtu.be/4jaBKXDqg9U?t=1807) which has an implementation of the ichimoku cloud you are trying to make. I watched it a while ago and it made sense to me. [Here](https://github.com/derekbanas/Python4Finance/blob/main/Ultimate%20Calc%20Stats.ipynb) is the source code if you don't wanna bother watching it.